# Unity comparing gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity by trying to do things and then when ofc failing (Because that's life about XD) then I'll try to find some scripts to learn from.

I was trying to make a smooth platformer controller and then ran into a video from Brackeys

I'm having trouble understanding this line of code:

```
        if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
        {
            m_Grounded = true;
            if (!wasGrounded)
                OnLandEvent.Invoke();
        }
```

(Full script can be found here: https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Character-Controller/blob/master/CharacterController2D.cs)

It's that line 54 the one that is making me have problems.

```
if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
```

What is he comparing? The first one is the gameobject attached to the collider but the second one is the default class, can someone explain what is he trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `Monobehvaiour` inherits from component. So it has access to all its properties `gameObject`, `transform` ..etc. Check [component documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html)

So in the snippet

```
if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
    {
        m_Grounded = true;
        if (!wasGrounded)
            OnLandEvent.Invoke();
    }
```

you are comparing the specific array's object (`colliders[i].gameObject`) with the current monobehaviour the code is running in (`gameObject` or `this.gameObject`).
In a class, you can access all the `public` and `protected` members it inherits from skypping the `this` keyword, as it can be understood you refer to the current instance by default.

Hope that makes sense.